# How do I run a program as admin without entering user credentials?

Tags: windows-7, administrator, uac, credentials

*You're probably going to say [DUPE!](https://superuser.com/questions/130803/run-program-as-admin-without-entering-credentials-automatic-win7-elevation) but that question's answer is specifically for a batch file command while mine isn't*

I have a domain that is running a program on all computers (Win7 and XP).  In order for the Windows 7 systems to run the program properly, they have to "run as an administrator".  Since these workstations are connected to a domain, that means that an admin has to be able to enter his/her credentials in order to run that program.  All users need to be able to access this program, and I really don't want to grant ALL users in the domain admin access.  Is there a way to run a *single* program as an admin without entering admin credentials?

Comment: Do they need admin to the Windows 7 computer or the server? Is it really the program (executable) or folder(other resource) they need access to as admin?

Comment: I've added the users as admins on local computer.  I don't want to add them as admins on domain. @JohnDR

Comment: Take the time to figure out why that program needs admin access, modify the filesystem, registry, and other acls to permit the program to run without being admin.

Answer (score 0):

The Encrypted RunAs utility that I mentioned in the answer to that question will also allow you to create a shortcut that runs the program.  (DUPE!!  Sorry, had to say it.)

Answer (score 0):

If you know what resources the program requires, you can grant permission for each of those resources to be used by "Users".  Generally, this is:

**Folders:**
C:\Program Files\Manufacturer\Application
C:\ProgramData\Manufacturer\Application
**Registry:**
HKLM\Software\Manufacturer\Application